# Entity Framework Code First: Computed property of type Type causes ArgumentNullException on Update-Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

As far as I understood, property of type Type cannot be directly stored in a database. Thus, I decided to create a wrapper - I want Entity Framework to store type name and create a property to return desired type:

```
[Table("DescriptiveCategory")]
public class DescriptiveCategory : Category {

    public string RelatedTypeName { get; set; }

    public Type RelatedType {
        get {
            return Type.GetType(RelatedTypeName);
        }
        set {
            RelatedTypeName = value.FullName;
        }
    }
}
```

This, unfortunately, does not work: if I try to update database, I get

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: extent
```

If I comment `RelatedType` property, everything is fine. But I don't want Entity Framework to anything with this property - it serves only my needs. I could probably create get and set methods instead but I don't understand why this approach (with computed properties) doesn't work.

Comment: Try the NotMappedAttribute

Comment: @ta.speot.is that should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NotMappedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx):

> Denotes that a property or class should be excluded from database mapping.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, if someone explains why Entity Framework cares about this particular computed property, I'd be very glad.

Comment: Well according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11902129/242520 it's because you have a property that's implicitly mapped to the database of type `Type`. No mapping of `Type` is possible, as you are aware.

Comment: Understood. But why is it implicitly mapped, when it's just a calculated property? Or more generally: When are calculated properties implicitly mapped and when not?

Comment: What's the difference between `int Something { get; set; }`, `int Something { get { return _something; } { set { _something = value; } }` and `int Something { get { return a*b; } set { a = value; b = value; } }`? Properties are just syntactic sugar around `get_Something()` and `set_Something(int value)` methods. How does EF know a property method's implementation is for an auto-property or something more complex?